# How to select the element I want using jQuery when there are hidden elements that are sometimes visible

Tags: jquery

I have a button that shows or hides a div that has a particular class on it using jQuery's `slideToggle()` function and it works fine, except when there's another div that was once hidden but is now visible in the mix.

I'm also using jQuery to select the div I'm after from inside my buttons' click event like so:

`$(".MyButton").click(function () {
    var theDiv = $(this).next(".TheDivImAfter");
    theDiv.slideToggle();
});`

I understand that jQuery's `next()` function literally only looks at the next element and that when there's an element between here and there that was once hidden but is now visible, the `next()` functions sees that instead and selects nothing since the classes don't match. And that makes sense.

I tried `nextUntil()` too and that also selects nothing, which doesn't make sense to me. I've also tried `find()`, `first()` and `siblings()` with varying degrees of success and ended up wondering why there isn't a `siblingsUntil()` because `.TheDivImAfter` and `.TheDivThatWasOnceHidden` are siblings.

And I've been trying pseudo selectors like `:not`:

`$(this).next(".TheDivImAfter:not(.TheDivThatWasOnceHidden)");`

But it's still not working in those instances.

Is there any way to have it skip or ignore the class that's on the div that was once hidden?

I appreciate any help anyone can offer, I'm still wondering why `nextUntil()` doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Including HTML will help clarify your question and get you a resolution faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are after `nextAll()`.  Here are the differences as per the `jQuery` API;

**nextAll()**

> Description: Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

**nextUntil()**

> Description: Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.

[Traversal Functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

You can see that the primary difference is that `nextUntil` excludes the element matched by the selector provided.  Both functions will take a filter to get to the exact `div` you are after.

```
$(".MyButton").click(function () {
    var theDiv = $(this).nextAll(".TheDivImAfter");
    theDiv.slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: 'nextUntil()' is exclusive, thanks @Steve0! 'nextAll()' is what I was after except there can be more than one, so I just put a 'first()' after that and it's working perfectly!